# Uniform Convergence for Functions $X \to [0,+\infty]$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence, measurable-functions

An exercise in Tao's *Introduction to Measure Theory* asks to show that if $(X,\mathcal{B}, \mu)$ is a finite measure space and $f_n : X \to [0,+\infty]$ is a sequence of unsigned $\mathcal{B}$-measurable functions that converge uniformly to a limit function $f : X \to [0,+\infty]$, then $\int_X f_n\,d\mu$ converges to $\int_X f\,d\mu$.

But wait! $[0,+\infty]$ is not naturally a metric space, so I'm not sure how to interpret uniform convergence here. Should I modify the problem to only consider measurable functions $X \to [0,+\infty)$, or is there a way to recover a meaningful statement that applies to all unsigned measurable functions?

Edit: Added finiteness hypothesis

Comment: Do you claim that the text never previously defined such uniform convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\artanh}{\operatorname{artanh}}$$[0,+\infty]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and any choice of homeomorphism gives a compatible metric. For example, you could use $\rho(x,y)=|\artanh(x)-\artanh(y)|$ (with $\artanh(\infty):=1$) and define uniform convergence in this sense. There is a more general notion involving [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

But for the particular theorem at hand, it doesn't really matter. Excise the set on which $f=\infty$ - call the resulting subspace $Y:=X\setminus f^{-1}\{\infty\}$ - and consider the usual notion of uniform convergence for functions valued in $[0,\infty)$; for large enough $n$, $f_n$ should also take finite values if the sequence can be reasonably said to uniformly converge. You may add that as an extra assumption if you wish. Then the theorem will show $\int_Y f_n\to\int_Yf$.

If $\mu(f^{-1}\{\infty\})=0$ then $\int_Yf=\int_Xf$ and $\int_Yf_n=\int_Xf_n$ so there is no difference. If $\mu(f^{-1}\{\infty\})>0$ then $\int_X f$ is infinite and we must show that $\int_X f_n$ diverges too. To have a notion of uniform convergence here, we could just say (as a reasonable but ad hoc notion):

> For all $M>0$ there is $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $f_n(x)>M$ if $n>N$ and $x\in f^{-1}\{\infty\}$.

In that case, it is clear that $\int_X f_n$ diverges (using nonnegativity...) and thus the difference between $[0,\infty)$ and $[0,\infty]$ is immaterial. The real content of the theorem lies in handling the finite case.

Note that this ad hoc definition of uniform convergence on $f^{-1}\{\infty\}$ agrees with the notions imposed by metrics like $\rho(x,y)=|\artanh(x)-\artanh(y)|$. The choice of metric should be irrelevant.

Comment: Cool answer. That $[0, \infty]$ might have been a typo in the book.

Comment: @FShrike Makes a lot of sense, thanks! I was toying with the notion of endowing $[0,+\infty]$ with a metric via a homeomorphism with $[0,1]$, but I wasn't sure that all such homeomorphisms generate the same definition of uniform convergence on $[0,+\infty]$. I dare say that this is a very special property of $[0,1]$, reliant on the fact that all homeomorphisms $[0,1] \to [0,1]$ are increasing or decreasing. Is this correct?

Comment: @NickA. It is more of a consequence of the compactness of $[0,+\infty]$ which gives you that there is one and only one "uniform structure" on $[0,+\infty]$ compatible with its topology.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I doubt it's a typo; Tao consistently allows unsigned measurable functions to attain the value $+\infty$ throughout the text. FWIW I really like the generality of this treatment and wish more texts adopted it.

Comment: @NickA. See Tuong's comment about the uniqueness issue. At any rate, the ad hoc uniform convergence to infinity definition (i) fits the metric ones and (ii) makes the theorem work and (iii) makes a lot of sense and doesn't rely on arbitrary choice of metric, so, you can work with that!

Comment: @P.P.Tuong Makes sense! Just sketched out a proof and compactness was indeed the crucial property.

Comment: @FShrike About your claim that "for large enough $n$, $f_n$
 should also take finite values if the sequence can be reasonably said to uniformly converge": If we define uniform convergence in terms of a homeomorphism $[0,1] \to [0,+\infty]$, this might not be true. Consider the functions $f_n:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ that round up to the nearest multiple of $2^{-n}$, and pick any homeomorphism $\phi : [0,1] \to [0,+\infty]$ sending $1$ to $+\infty$. Then $\phi \circ f_n$ converges uniformly to $\phi$, but excising $\{1\} = \phi^{-1}(+\infty)$ does not stop the $\phi \circ f_n$ from becoming infinite

Comment: @NickA. If $0\le x<1$ then for **large enough** $n$ $\phi(f_n(x))$ is finite

Comment: @FShrike Is it? My understanding is that $\phi(f_n(x)) = \infty$ for $x \in (1-2^{-n},1]$. No matter how big $n$ gets, $\phi \circ f_n$ will always attain $+\infty$ somewhere in $[0,1)$.

Comment: @NickA. We are both correct in our most recent comments. But thinking about it a bit more, you’re right that the metric definition doesn’t fit what I said at the top (“… finite for large $n$, you can add this as a hypothesis if you wish.”) Perhaps this can be salvaged though if we establish a general triangle inequality $\int\rho(f_n,f)\le\rho(\int f_n,\int f)$; if that’s true (which I don’t know) then just using the metric definition would work. Hmm.